# thread creation in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

The requirement is: Need to start a background process on click of a link.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.generateReport}"> 
<h:outputText value="Generate Report"/>  
</h:commandLink>
```

in the thread - run(),

```
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
    createReport(); 
    }
```

and in the createReport method,

```
public String createReport() 
{

            DatabaseAPI data = new DatabaseAPI();
            MyUser ip_user = (MyUser) sesFactory.get().getAttribute(ProjConstants.SESSION_USER_VAR);

            try 
                    {
                   data.generateReportFunction( .. arguments ..)
            } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "failure";
            }
            return "success";
}
```

in the createReport method, the thread get stopped in the following line:

```
DatabaseAPI data = new DatabaseAPI();
```

if i comment that line then it get stopped in this line:

```
MyUser ip_user = (MyUser) sesFactory.get().getAttribute(ProjConstants.SESSION_USER_VAR);
```

my managed bean scope is : request.

even i comment some lines as below : still the thread get stopped

```
public String createReport() 
    {

                DatabaseAPI data = new DatabaseAPI();
                //MyUser ip_user = (MyUser) sesFactory.get().getAttribute(ProjConstants.SESSION_USER_VAR);

                try 
                        {
                      // data.generateReportFunction( .. arguments ..)
                } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "failure";
                }
                return "success";
    }
```

Comment: can you please add code for that `DatabaseAPI` class and the `sesFactory` class attribute?

Comment: my doubt is how instance creation ( DatabaseAPI data = new DatabaseAPI(); ) itself block/stop a thread execution.? or i need to check anything else ?

Comment: we can't tell how that can block anything without seeing the actual code, you should update your question